# Android - Unit Test to check if cursor is clsoed

Tags: android, sqlite, unit-testing

I run in to this error:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 2062): Could not open database
#################################################################
Error Code : 2062 (SQLITE_CANTOPEN_EMFILE)
Caused By : Application has opened too many files. Maximum of available file descriptors in one process is 1024 in default.
(unknown error (code 2062): Could not open database)
#################################################################
```

I think this happend because I forgot to close a cursor in a method. To be save I want to reproduce this problem in a unit test. But I don't know how to check how many connections/cursor are existing and how assert that exception

```
public int getServicesAmount() {
    int servicesAmount;
    AppDbHelper dbHelper = new AppDbHelper(context);
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    String[] columns = {/* some columns */};

    Cursor cursor = db.query(
            AppEntryContract.ServiceEntry.TABLE,
            columns,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null
    );
    servicesAmount = cursor.getCount();
    // here I should close the cursor
    return servicesAmount;
}
```

This is the the unit test so far

```
 @Test
public void connectionNotClosed() throws Exception {

    try
    {
        Storage storage = new Storage(RuntimeEnvironment.application);
        for(int i = 0; i <= 1025; i++) {
            storage.getServicesAmount();
        }
        Assert.fail();
    }
    catch(ArithmeticException e)
    {
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("----------------- SUCCESS -------------------");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
        assertThat("",is(""));
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. one instance of `SQLiteOpenHelper` should be enough 2. there is no need to close `SQLiteDatabase` (if it's not closed then SQLiteOpenHelper returns the same instance for getReadableDatabase or geWritableDatabase)  3. you should remeber to close `Cursor`

Comment: thanks for your comment. Sorry, I mixed up db connection and cursor in the description. my bad